# GetColumName(i) returns "" when using UNION (Jaybird)

Tags: java, union, firebird, jaybird

I'm a little bit confused with my new SQL query using a union.

I request my firebird db in a java app using jaybird 2.2.8. Usually I parse my ResultSet using the MetaData

```
ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
```

and looping through the columns

```
for (int i = 1; i <= metaData.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            columnName = metaData.getColumnName(i);
            int columnType = metaData.getColumnType(i);
            switch (columnType) { ...
```

This was working quite well until I started using a Union in my SQL query.
Now the method

```
metaData.getColumnName(i)
```

returns an empty string instead of the column name - the column type is valid.

When I use a SQL query without Union everything works as expected and when I test my query in IBExpert all columns have a a valid name.

Any idea whats wrong? Does anybody has a workaround?

Btw. the ResultSet looks quite well in the eclipse debugger

Comment: Try `getColumnLabel(i)`. As a work-around you might try explicit column labels: `... AS col1, ... AS col2`.

Comment: @JoopEggen Alias don't map to `columnName`, only to `columnLabel`

Comment: @MarkRotteveel good clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the `getColumnName` you need to use [`getColumnLabel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnLabel-int-). The column name only has a value if the value is guaranteed to come from a single column in a single table, which is not the case in a `UNION`. In the case of a `UNION`, Firebird handles the name of columns (or the alias if specified) in the first select as aliases (labels) only; it doesn't preserve the column name as a column name that can be returned by `getColumnName`.

If you really need to use `getColumnName` (eg for compatibility reasons), then you can use the Jaybird connection property `columnLabelForName=true`, but this is discouraged because it is not compliant with JDBC. In almost all cases you should use `getColumnLabel` instead.

The distinction between column name and column label is subtle, and wasn't really clear in older JDBC specification. Basically column name is the name of the column in the original table, while the column label is the 'name' (or more correctly: label) of the column in the result set. The label is either the alias specified with `AS`, or - if no alias is specified - the original column name as returned by `getColumnName`.

See also:

- [Changes and fixes in Jaybird 2.2.1](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/drivers_documentation/java/2.2.15/release_notes.html#changes-and-fixes-in-jaybird-2.2.1)
- [Compatibility with com.sun.rowset.*](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/drivers_documentation/java/2.2.15/release_notes.html#compatibility-with-com.sun.rowset.)

Disclosure: I am one of the Jaybird developers

Comment: But from my point of view this is not so clear from the java doc 
return column name in `getColumnName` 
vs. 
return the suggested column title in getColumnLabel. 
In particular with the doc fom `getColumnLabel`
"If a SQL <code>AS</code> is not specified, the value returned from
     * <code>getColumnLabel</code> will be the same as the value returned by the
     * <code>getColumnName</code> method."

Comment: @Maick The columnName <> columnLabel thing is unfortunately one of the things in JDBC that is not 100% clear (although it has improved over what was specified in JDBC 2.0 iirc). That no columnName is communicated here is an implementation detail of Firebird; there may well be databases where the columnName is populated in this case, however you almost always need to use columnLabel anyway (for example retrieving values from the result set is either done by column index or the column label), so I wouldn't dwell on it too much.